# Sqlite query from objective C to java

Tags: java, android, objective-c, eclipse, sqlite

I am trying to translate some of code of Objective C in java for android. I am new to android, please if anyone can help me how can i execute these queries.

The following code is in objective C

```
 private int getNextAccountIdForUserId (String userId, AccountType accountType)
    {
        int nextId = kFirstIDValue;  //initial value is 0;
        String queryString = "SELECT MAX(accountId) FROM MAAccounts WHERE userId = ? AND accountType = ?";
        ResultSet resultSet = [_db executeQuery:queryString, [self stringToDB:userId], [self integerToDB:accountType], nil];
        if([resultSet next])
        {
            int currentMax = [resultSet intForColumnIndex:0];

            nextId = currentMax + 1;
        }

        [resultSet close];

        return  nextId;

    }
```

if anyone can tell me how can i execute this query in java sqlite.

```
String queryString = "SELECT MAX(accountId) FROM MAAccounts WHERE userId = ? AND accountType = ?";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use something like this

```
String[] whereVars = new String[] {userId, accountType};
String queryString = "SELECT MAX(accountId) FROM MAAccounts WHERE userId = ? AND accountType = ?";
Cursor cursor = dbHandle.rawQuery(queryString, whereVars);
```

Comment: accountType type is "AccountType". Will it work still? or if the type is int or anyother what will happen